# AviSynth: How to resize video to 480, keeping aspect ratio

Tags: aspect-ratio, avisynth, ps3-media-server

How can i resize a video to 480 pixels high in AviSynth, while maintaining aspect ratio? Assume, for simplicity sake, the Bilinear resize.

i've tried:

```
source = DirectShowSource("TheClip.avi")
resized = BilinearResize(source, target_height=480)
return resized
```

But that gives the error

> Script error: Invalid arguments to function "BilinearResize"

---

**Note**: The reason i don't supply a `width` is that i don't *know* a width. The script is being used by a [media server](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/), that [now forces the use of **AviSynth** in order to perform resizing](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=104). i don't *know* the size of any video that anyone might choose to play - but i do know i need it resized to x480.

i presume AviSynth can do something like:

```
resized=BilinearResize(source, source.width*480/source.height, 480)
```

but that also fails:

> Resize: YUY2 destination width must be even

i could keep going, trying to find a way to [AddBorders](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/AddBorders) or [Crop](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Crop), to make the width [mod4, mod8, or mod16](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Crop#Crop_restrictions).  Or i could ask here and maybe there already is a way to perform aspect-preserving scaling.

Comment: Is there a way to cast ( source.width*480/source.height) to an int or something?

Comment: i'm pretty sure the problem is that the width it's calculating is something like 691x480. This conflicts with YUY2 which stores one color value for each *pair* of pixels; and this video is one pair short (should be 690x480 or 691x480)

Comment: So is there a round function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty with avisynth scripting, but I think this should work to get the width, based in a target height of 480, and a given modulo value... I couldn't test it as I don't have avisynth installed ...

```
 srceH = source.height
 srceW = source.width
    AR = (float(srceW) / float(srceH))
 targH = 480
 targW = int(float(targH) * AR)
 coMod = 4   # The codec modulo requirement 
 targW = ((targW / coMod) * coMod)
```

Comment: you missed setting the aspect variable. 
but after that it works great, thanks

Comment: Thanks *yoshco*... Yes, I had *AR* in one place and *aspect* in another... Changed to *AR*.